# Javascript Iterate elements of a first array at the position of another second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

hello i have the following code

```
let names = ["josh","tony","daniel"];  
let arrayplaces = ["30", "60", "90"];

names.forEach((elem, indexed) => {
  const num2 = arrayplaces[indexed];
  console.log('The user ' + elem + ' iterated in place ' + num2);
});
```

What I'm looking for is to iterate through all the elements of the first array into the first element of the second array, ending with the first one and continuing until it goes through the entire second array.

```
Example of the expected output:

The user josh iterated in place 30
The user tony iterated in place 30
The user daniel iterated in place 30

The user josh iterated in place 60
The user tony iterated in place 60
The user daniel iterated in place 60

The user josh iterated in place 90
The user tony iterated in place 90
The user daniel iterated in place 90
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Loop over `arrayplaces` and inside that loop have another one that loops over the names.

Comment: Please try: ``console.log(arrayplaces.flatMap(ap => names.map(nm => (`The user ${nm} iterated in place ${ap}`))).join('\n'));`` and share your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by nesting loop both the array.

```js
let names = ["josh","tony","daniel"];  
let arrayplaces = ["30", "60", "90"];

arrayplaces.forEach((element)=>{
  names.forEach((elem) => {
  console.log('The user ' + elem + ' iterated in place ' + element);
  });
 console.log('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over both arrays.

```
for (let place of arrayplaces) {
    for (let name of names) {
        console.log(`The user ${name} iterated in place ${place}`)
    }
    console.log('\n')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just should eterate every value of `arrayplaces` with every name. You should use 2 cycles to do that.

```js
const names = ['josh', 'tony', 'daniel'];
const arrayplaces = ['30', '60', '90'];

names.forEach((elem, indexed) => {
  names.forEach((elem2) => {
    const num2 = arrayplaces[indexed];
    console.log(`The user ${elem2} iterated in place ${num2}`);
  });
});
```